# Professional grade Expandable and Contactable tubing - similar to Slinky Pop Tubing

Tags: pipe, hose

I would like to find some kind of tubing, piping, or hose that I can both make longer and shorter, but just as importantly, with a material that even when expanded doesn't 'slag' down, that the material is strong enough to extend horizontally a couple of feet without need of an intermediate support; such as the slinky pop tubing as seen in the video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Z0hs2p7YN4

Now there are lots of small diameter tubes such as the one in the video, but seem to be used for toys. I am hoping to find something more professional grade that can be contracted/expanded hundreds of times, has a few inch radius. A plus if I can send water through it.

Thanks,

Brian

Comment: Can you tell us the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use extendable rain-gutter downspout extension tubes during the rainy season. Very similar to your "pop-tube" but 3"-4" diameter heavy vinyl (and made to "send water through". They support their own weight reasonably well, but would sag if fully extended. If you only expanded **some** of the folds (like every 3rd fold?) it would increase rigidity.

[image]